# Route single IPv6 address using router advertisement

Tags: routing, ipv6, radvd

I have a server in my local network that connects to an external VPN server and gets assigned the public IP address `2a02:c200:1:10:3:0:4315:2`. Currently, when other computers in my local network access the server using its public IP address, the connection is naturally routed over the internet via the VPN server. I would like to set up my network to route connections to the public IP address of the server locally.

Basically, I need to set up a route `2a02:c200:1:10:3:0:4315:2/128 via fe80::baae:edff:fe79:122` (which is the local address of the server).

The router in my local network does not let me specify static IPv6 routes. So I am trying to set up a router advertisement on the server that advertises the route automatically. Unfortunately, I cannot find any documentation about advertising routes with radvd.

Like in [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/437271/advertise-a-subnet-route-with-radvd/437768), I have configured radvd as follows:

```
interface enp0s25 {
    AdvSendAdvert on;
    AdvDefaultLifetime 0;

    route 2a02:c200:1:10:3:0:4315:2/128 {
    };
};
```

This is the advertisement that arrives on my computer (shown using `radvdump`):

```
#
# radvd configuration generated by radvdump 2.11
# based on Router Advertisement from fe80::baae:edff:fe79:122
# received by interface wlp2s0
#

interface wlp2s0
{
    AdvSendAdvert on;
    # Note: {Min,Max}RtrAdvInterval cannot be obtained with radvdump
    AdvManagedFlag off;
    AdvOtherConfigFlag off;
    AdvReachableTime 0;
    AdvRetransTimer 0;
    AdvCurHopLimit 64;
    AdvDefaultLifetime 0;
    AdvHomeAgentFlag off;
    AdvDefaultPreference medium;
    AdvSourceLLAddress on;

    route 2a02:c200:1:10::/128
    {
        AdvRouteLifetime 30;
    }; # End of route definition

}; # End of interface definition
```

As you can see, the route prefix got truncated for some reason. Unrelated to that, my computer (Linux) does not set up any route, despite setting `net.ipv6.conf.all.accept_ra_rt_info_max_plen = 128`.

Before I added `AdvDefaultLifetime 0;`, a route `default via fe80::baae:edff:fe79:122` was set up, which is not supposed to be, so I followed the advice from [this mail](https://lists.debian.org/debian-ipv6/2009/01/msg00001.html) to add this parameter.

Does anyone have an idea what I could be doing wrong, or a link to some documentation about advertising routes with radvd?

Comment: Hmm, that should work.

Comment: Do you have any idea why the prefix gets cut off?

Comment: @cdauth Did you inspect the traffic on the wire to see if it got truncated before or after being sent over the network?